# Let $f$ be a $C^2$ function on $\mathbb{R}$. Assume that $f$ is bounded with bounded second derivative.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A=\sup_{x}|f(x)|$ and $B=\sup_x|f''(x)|$. Prove that $\sup_x|f'(x)|\leq2\sqrt{AB}$.

Comment: are you sure that is $\sup_x|f'(x)|\leq\sqrt{AB}$ ?? I'm sure the best one can tell is $\sup_x|f'(x)|\leq\sqrt{2AB}$ (there is a function where equality holds).

Comment: I forgot to add 2 in front of AB, thanks for your correction

Answer (score 2):

By the Mean Value Theorem, for some $c\in(a-h,a)$
$$
f'(c)=\frac{f(a)-f(a-h)}{h}\tag{1}
$$
Then
$$
f'(a)-f'(c)=\int_c^a f''(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{2}
$$
The triangle inequality and $(1)$ and $(2)$ yield
$$
\begin{align}
|f'(a)|
&\le|f'(c)|+|f'(a)-f'(c)|\\[9pt]
&=\left|\,\frac{f(a)-f(a-h)}{h}\,\right|
+\left|\,\int_c^a f''(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\,\right|\\
&\le\frac{2A}{h}+hB\\[9pt]
&=2\sqrt{AB}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
using $h=2\sqrt{\frac{A}{B}}$

Comment: Equality case :: $f:(-1,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$
$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{l}2x^2-1&\text{if }x\lt0\\ \frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}&\text{if }0 \le x \end{array}\right.$$

Comment: @r9m: Ah, I see... the domain has been changed to $(-1,\infty)$. So in a domain bounded on one side, it seems my estimate is sharp.

Answer (score 1):

Since for $h>0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the MVT's,

\begin{align}
f(x+h)&=f(x)+hf'(x)+\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x+\theta h) \\
f(x-h)&=f(x)-hf'(x)+\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x-\theta' h)
\end{align}
for $\theta,\theta'\in (x-h,x+h)$.

Consequently, $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2h}(f(x+h)-f(x-h))+\frac{h}{4}(f''(x+\theta h)-f''(x-\theta' h))$

which implies $|f'(x)|\le \frac{A}{h}+\frac {h}{2}B$, for $h>0$. Take $h=\sqrt{2\frac{A}{B}}$, to get $\sup_x|f'(x)|\le \sqrt{2AB}$.

Comment: This appears to be a better bound (by a factor of $\sqrt2$) using Taylor Series (bigger missiles flatten bigger mountains). (+1)

Comment: $$f(x)= \left\{\begin{array}{l}-1&\text{if }x\lt-1\\ (x+1)^2-1&\text{if }-1 \le x\lt0\\ 1-(x-1)^2&\text{if }0\le x\lt1\\ 1&\text{if }x\ge1 \end{array}\right.$$ has $A=1$ and $B=2$ and $f'(0)=2$