# Existence of a function with boundary conditions for derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Does there exist a function $f\in C^2(\Bbb{R},\Bbb{R})$ such that $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\rightarrow_{x\rightarrow\infty}+\infty$ but $\frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}\rightarrow_{x\rightarrow\infty} 0$ ?

I know for the converse the answer is no using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808965/show-that-fx-le-frac2m-0h-frachm-22-and-m-1-le-2-sqrtm-0m/808980#808980) but I do not have idea for this question.

Comment: The limits are not specified. If you accept $x\rightarrow 0$ as a possible limit, then consider $f(x)=x$ as an example of such function (f"/f' is identically 0).

Comment: @Avitus I edited. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $f' = g(x)f$ with $g(x) \to +\infty$ as $x \to \infty$. Then $f'' = g'(x)f + g(x)f'$. Hence

$$\frac{f''}{f'} = g'(x)\frac{f}{f'}+g(x) = \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}+g(x)$$

So we need to find a $g$ with $g(x)\to+\infty$ such that $\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}+g(x) = h(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Using Wolfram Alpha to solve $\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}+g(x) = h(x)$, we get

$$g(x) = \frac{e^{H(x)}}{\int_1^x e^{H(t)}dt}$$

Where $H' = h$ (and we take the implicit constant to be 0). However,

$$e^{H(x)} \leq \int_1^x e^{H(t)}dt$$

Hence $g(x) \leq 1$, which contradicts the fact that $g(x) \to +\infty$. And we get that no such $g$ exists and therefore no such $f$ exists.

Comment: Nice. Thanks (+1)