# Can we do this by Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be twice differentiable, and suppose that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $|f(x)| \le 1$ and $|f''(x)|\le 1$. Prove that $|f'(x)| \le 2$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

My Attempt so far,

For the interval $(x,0)$
$$\frac{f'(x)-f'(0)}{x-0}=f''(x) \le 1$$
Now what next to do after this??

Comment: The equality that you wrote in your attempt is just false. Try again.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808965/show-that-fx-le-frac2m-0h-frachm-22-and-m-1-le-2-sqrtm-0m?rq=1