# Spivak, Ch. 20, Problem 22a: If $|f'|\leq M_0$, $f''\leq M_2$, prove $|f'(x)|\leq \frac{2}{h}M_0+\frac{h}{2}M_2, \text{ for all } h>0$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, taylor-expansion

The following is a problem from Spivak's *Calculus*. Questions have been asked about this problem before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808965/show-that-fx-le-frac2m-0h-frachm-22-and-m-1-le-2-sqrtm-0m) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703678/let-f-be-a-c2-function-on-mathbbr-assume-that-f-is-bounded-with-bou), though those problems are formulated slightly differently.

The current question regards specifically the formulation below.

To cut to the chase, I will show the solution manual solution and then my own solution. They apparently differ by a very small detail. I'd like to know if the detail is important for the solutions to be technically correct.

> 22. (a) Suppose that $f$ is twice differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ and that $|f(x)|\leq M_0$ for all $x>0$, while $|f''(x)|\leq M_2$ for all
>     $x>0$. Use an appropriate Taylor polynomial to prove that for any
>     $x>0$ we have
>
> $$|f'(x)|\leq \frac{2}{h}M_0+\frac{h}{2}M_2, \text{ for all } h>0$$

**The solution manual solution is as follows**

By Taylor's theorem with $n=1$ we have

$$f(a+h)=f(a)+f'(a)h+\frac{f''(t)}{2!}(a+h-t)^2, t\in (a,a+h)\tag{1}$$

$$|f'(a)|=\left | \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}-\frac{f''(t)}{2}\frac{(a+h-t)^2}{h} \right |\tag{2}$$

$$\leq \left | \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} \right | +\left | \frac{f''(t)}{2}\frac{(a+h-t)^2}{h} \right |\tag{3}$$

$$\leq \frac{2M_0}{h}+\frac{hM_2}{2}\tag{4}$$

The interval being considered is $(0,\infty)$. That is, both $x=a+h$ and $a$ are in this interval. And the problem statement says we must consider all $x>0$ and all $h>0$, which means that $a$ is chosen as a function of the former two choices.

**But how is this possible?**
If we choose $x=1$ and $h=2$, then isn't $a=-1$?

**Here is my own solution.**

It seems to be technically almost the same, except perhaps for the specification of $h$.

$$f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{f''(t)}{2}(x-t)^2, t\in (a,x) \text{ or } t\in (x,a)$$

$$f'(a)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-\frac{f''(t)}{2}\frac{(x-t)^2}{x-a}$$

$$|f'(a)|=\left | \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-\frac{f''(t)}{2}\frac{(x-t)^2}{x-a} \right |$$

$$\leq \left | \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \right | +\left | \frac{f''(t)}{2}\frac{(x-t)^2}{x-a} \right |$$

Let $h>0$. Given an $a$, choose $x$ such that $h=|x-a|$.

Note that since

$$-M_0\leq f(x)\leq M_0$$
$$-M_0\leq f(a)\leq M_0$$

Then

$$-2M_0\leq f(x)-f(a)\leq 2M_0$$

$$|f(x)-f(a)|\leq 2M_0$$

Also, since $t\in (a,x)$ or $t\in (x,a)$ then $$x-t<h\implies (x-t)^2<h^2$$

Hence

$$|f'(a)|\leq \frac{2M_0}{h}+\frac{M_2}{2}\frac{h^2}{h}=\frac{2M_0}{h}+\frac{hM_2}{2}$$

By choosing $x$ after $a$ and $h$, we can choose $x$ larger than $a$ if $h>a$.

**Questions**

- Is the solution manual solution technically correct?
- Is my solution technically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion your solution seems to be technically correct and identical to the solution from the manual.

The solution manual works with $a=x$! So it has shown, for any $a,h>0$, that: $$|f'(a)|\le\frac{2}{h}M_0+\frac{h}{2}M_2$$Which is identical to showing that, for all $x,h>0$: $$|f'(x)|\le\frac{2}{h}M_0+\frac{h}{2}M_2$$

Comment: In my last equation I had a typo. It is $|f'(a)|\leq$ not $|f'(x)|\leq$. Hence, I too have shown the result for any $a,h>0$. Thus, to summarize, we pick any $a>0$ about which to compute the Taylor polynomial, and any $h>0$. Then, by computing the value of the Taylor polynomial at $x=a+h>0$ we can show that $f'(a)\leq \frac{2M_0}{h}+\frac{hM_2}{2}$.

Comment: Your final inequality shall still hold with $a\mapsto x$. What's the problem?

Comment: No problem, I agree with your conclusion now.

Answer (score 0):

Your summary of the solution manual's argument is incorrect. However, this is not really your fault, as the solution manual *itself* has an obvious typo in it that makes it pretty ambiguous what the argument was intended to be in the first place - and perhaps you attempted to rectify this using your own interpretation. Specifically, Spivak's argument involves the usage of a remainder term that does not adhere to the structure of any remainder covered in the book (as I will now show).

Spivak's opening line reads as:

> $$f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+\frac{f''(t)}{2}(x+h-t)h \quad \text{for some $t\in(x,x+h)$}$$

This equation is incorrect, as it blends the Lagrange interpretation of the remainder with the Cauchy interpretation of the remainder. If the Cauchy interpretation was used, then the following argument should have been written:

It will be easier to think of $f(x+h)$ as $F(h)$. Next, consider the Taylor polynomial representation of $F$ with $n=1$, $a=0$, and the Cauchy remainder, which we would write as:

$$F(h)=\frac{F^{(0)}(0)}{0!}(h-0)^0+\frac{F^{(1)}(0)}{1!}(h-0)^1+\frac{F^{(2)}(z)}{1!}(h-z)^1(h-0)^1 \quad \text{for some $z \in (0,h)$}$$

Under this interpretation, we are assuming that $h$ is positive, but the argument works just as well if $h$ is negative.

This simplifies to:

$$F(h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+f''(x+z)(h-z)^1(h-0)^1 \quad \text{for some $z \in (0,h)$}$$

Next, let $t=x+z$. Given that $z \in (0,h)$, we must have that $t\in(x,x+h)$. Next, $t=x+z \rightarrow-z=x-t \rightarrow h-z=x+h-t$. Therefore, we can rewrite our equation as $\forall h \gt 0 :\forall x \in \mathbb R$:

$$F(h)=f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+f''(t)(x+h-t)h\quad\text{for some $t \in (x,x+h)$}$$ Comparing this with the solution manual, you can see that there is no $\frac{1}{2}$ in the remainder term. There is no point in continuing with this approach, as we will never recover the $\frac{1}{2}$ factor that is necessary to prove the desired statement.

Instead, let us use the Lagrange interpretation.  Then we would write:

\begin{align}F(h)&=\frac{F^{(0)}(0)}{0!}(h-0)^0+\frac{F^{(1)}(0)}{1!}(h-0)^1+\frac{F^{(2)}(z)}{2!}(h)^2 \\
&=f(x)+f'(x)h+\frac{f''(x+z)}{2}h^2 \quad \text{for some $z \in (0,h)$}\end{align}

At this point, we are assuming $h\gt 0$ (by virtue of defining the interval as $(0,h)$), and we have made no  claim  about which interval $x$ belongs to. Let us now assert that $x \gt 0$. You may ask "but how do we deal with $h \lt 0$?" Well, because $x \gt 0$, we can always find an $h$ sufficiently small such that $x+h \gt 0$ (even if $h \lt 0$...i.e. even if we claim that $z\in (h,0)$). Applying our same $t$ substitution as earlier, we then have:

$$f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+\frac{f''(t)}{2}h^2 \quad \text{for some $t \in (x,x+h)$} \quad (\dagger)$$

In the event $h \lt 0$, this would still read exactly the same except we would have $t\in(x+h,x)$ and, more importantly, $(x+h,x) \subset (0,\infty)$ assuming $h$ was sufficiently small. If you refer to the problem statement, Spivak only wants us to deal with $h \gt 0$, though, so who really even cares about the case where $h \lt 0$.

Simplifying $(\dagger)$:

\begin{align} &f'(x)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-\frac{f''(t)h^2}{2h} \implies \\
&|f'(x)|=\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-\frac{f''(t)h^2}{2h}\right|\leq \left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right|+\left|\frac{f''(t)h}{2}\right| \implies \\
&|f'(x)|\leq \left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right|+\left|\frac{f''(t)h}{2}\right|\leq \left|\frac{f(x+h)}{h} \right|+\left|\frac{f(x)}{h}\right|+\frac{h}{2}|f''(t)|\end{align}

Recalling that we are working from $x \gt 0$ and $h \gt 0$, clearly $x+h \gt 0$ and $t \gt 0$. As such, we can apply the prompt's assumptions to conclude:

\begin{align} &|f'(x)|\leq \left|\frac{f(x+h)}{h} \right|+\left|\frac{f(x)}{h}\right|+\frac{h}{2}|f''(t)| \leq \frac{M_0}{h}+\frac{M_0}{h}+\frac{h}{2}M_2 \implies \\
&|f'(x)|\leq \frac{2}{h}M_0+\frac{h}{2}M_2\end{align}